# iOS: Check first time user logs in using Facebook - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication

I want to check whenever a user logs in using Facebook and has never authorised Facebook to use my app. In other words, the user has never logged in my app using Facebook.

This way I have 3 different cases:

- The user has never logged in: then after clicking on Login with Facebook a popup is shown to authorise his account to use facebook and a tutorial of my app is shown
- The user hasn't logged in but already authorised my app previously: then after clicking on Login with Facebook NO tutorial of my app will be shown
- The user already logged in the app, then no need to click on Login with Facebook and move to next screen. This is easy, I just use `if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])`

I have problems with the first case.

Comment: Unless you are planning on simply “asking” the user (“click here if you never logged in before”, …), this obviously can not be determined before the user logs in - because before login, you have no way of identifying the user. So you can only let them login, and then check if you have a record for their user id in your database already - and if not, show the tutorial then.

Comment: how are you maintaining authorization status in app?? for example, If it is saved in user-defaults , then check for status key. If key does not exists in default dictionaryRepresentation allkeys & If [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] is nil , then you can execute your first case..

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find the answer with your help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer. Every time the user registers for first time using Facebook, a key called "userFullName" is created and stored in the server. Then, I just have to check whether the key "userFullName" is null or not, that will determine whether the user logged in the app previously.

```
// if the user logged in the app previously, don't show tutorial:

if ([[GetUserNamefromServer userFullName!=NULL) {
     NSLog(@"User already registered");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:nil];
}


// if it's the first time the user logs in the app, show tutorial

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signup" sender:nil];
```